# Changes in install.packages() from R 3.1.2 to R 3.2.1

Tags: r, install.packages

I am working on a Windows 7 machine without internet access. As yet, I got around the missing internet connection by creating a local copy of the binary CRAN repository in `//server/x/bin/windows/contrib/3.1`, then running `write_PACKAGES("//server/x/bin/windows/contrib/3.1")` and finally setting `r["CRAN"]="file:////server/x";r["CRANextra"]=r["CRAN"];` in `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/etc/Rprofile.site`.

But this does not work any longer since R 3.2.1. The path in the error message of `install.packages` indicates that R is looking for the source package:

```
Cannot open compressed file '//server/x/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

I have thought that R on Windows only looks for binary packages!

Looking at a diff between `install.packages` for 3.1.2 and 3.2.1, I can see quite a few changes. However, the source code for the function has 500+ lines which makes it hard for me to see where specifically the problem lies.

I have tried to set

```
options(install.packages.check.source="no")
```

and to explicitly add `type="win.binary"` to `install.packages` - both without success.

It is also interesting that

```
contrib.url(options("repos")$repos["CRAN"],type="win.binary")
```

gives the correct path `file:////server/x/bin/windows/contrib/3.2` but somehow this is not used by `install.packages(...,type="win.binary")`...

So my question is whether you guys have experienced similar problems?

If no, I would be grateful for any pointers to mistakes I could have made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem.
The R 3.2.1 NEWS section (https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS) says

> - The default for option pkgType on platforms using binary packages   is now "both", so source packages will be tried if binary   versions
>     are not available or not up to date.

The problem is that RStudio does not directly call `install.packages` but via a few other functions such as `.rs.callAs`. In one of these functions, `available.packages()` gets called without any arguments. So it determines the argument `type` via `getOption("pkgType")`. But since R 3.2.1 this is now `"both"` and not `"win.binary"` as in R 3.1.2.

A quick workaround for the problem is thus to add

```
options(pkgType="win.binary")
```

to the `yourRinstallpath/etc/Rprofile.site`